# Build multiple .net projects using ant

Tags: .net, ant, build, build-process

I have multiple projects in different folders.I want to build each projects individually.
Since we are using ANT tool to build the java projects,Client wants us to use the ANT tool to build the .Net projects.

Could you please provide the guidance to do this.I have checked online ,but couldn't get much information on this.

There is a NAnt tool for.net projects .But the client wants us to use ANT.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: nant is for .net. ant is for java. i don't think you can use ant for .net.

Comment: There is a .NET Antlib - http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/dotnet/index.html - but it hasn't seen any updates in quite some time.